# Can I set the umask on a specific directory?

Tags: macos, unix, umask

I have a fairly restrictive umask setting (0077). This is fine, except I have one directory in which I'd like a more permissive setting (0002) to all files created anywhere under that directory. Is there a way to set a umask on a specific directory, so all files created beneath it inherit the same permissions?

Answer (score 6):

Use ACL's:

Normally, this command would work:

`setfacl -d -m mask:002 /your/dir/here/`

For MacOS you have to use `chmod`.
See: [manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/chmod.2.html).
See: [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/31448).

If wanting to have a different umask for a login, normally, you just add a `umask 002` to your shell .profile, or shell startup file. All new directories will use this if logged in under that profile/environment. But, please read about Mac umask, though, as it seems the way you get it to work *at login* depends on your OS version and using Mac `launchctl`.

See:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/27888296/503621 
See:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201684

Comment: Just a heads up: ACL's don't translate across a network. (Samba/NFS)... You will need to add to that to the individual network config file insead for the specific dir. (i.e. smb.conf - create mask = 775)

Comment: Actually, AFAIU NFS3 & NFS4 do support (some?) ACLs (at least on linux)?

Comment: And so does Samba...

Comment: Haven't had to try that in long, long time. Better safe than sorry (!) Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: This is for Mac OS X.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/6607/propagate-removal-of-an-acl-entry-for-just-one-user-in-mac-os Seems you will have to use 'chmod' if setfacl unavailable under bash.

Answer (score 1):

Provide anther solution implemented with **shell hooks** and [`direnv`](https://github.com/direnv/direnv). The following solution may be more compatible in case `setfacl` is not available on your system. (e.g. macOS)

> `direnv` is an environment switcher for the shell. It knows how to hook into bash, zsh, tcsh, fish shell and elvish to load or **unload** environment variables depending on the *current directory*.

Use `.envrc` to `export` custom `umask` value for specific dir, and the `export`ed env var will be unloaded when you leave that dir.

```bsh
# example .envrc file
export UMASK=0022
```

Define a hook to change the `umask` value once working dir is changed.

```bsh
function _umask_hook {
  if [[ -n $UMASK ]]; then
    umask "$UMASK"
  elif [[ $OSTYPE == darwin* ]]; then
    umask 0077
  else
    umask 0022
  fi
}

# To make the code more reliable on detecting the default umask
function _umask_hook {
  # Record the default umask value on the 1st run
  [[ -z $DEFAULT_UMASK ]] && export DEFAULT_UMASK="$(builtin umask)"

  if [[ -n $UMASK ]]; then
    umask "$UMASK"
  else
    umask "$DEFAULT_UMASK"
  fi
}

# zsh hooks
# trigger _umask_hook once working dir is changed
add-zsh-hook chpwd _umask_hook

# bash
# Append `;` if PROMPT_COMMAND is not empty
PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND;}_umask_hook"
```

For the time being, direnv hook initialization for zsh doesn't support `chpwd` hook. If the pull request [GH-514](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/pull/514) has not been merged when you see this page. Please comment out `eval "$(direnv hook zsh)"` and hook `direnv` on `chpwd` manually with following code,

```bsh
if (( $+commands[direnv] )) && ! (( $+functions[_direnv_hook] )); then
  _direnv_hook() {
    eval "$(command "direnv" export zsh)";
  }
  typeset -agU precmd_functions;
  if [[ -z ${precmd_functions[(r)_direnv_hook]} ]]; then
    precmd_functions=( _direnv_hook ${precmd_functions[@]} )
  fi

  typeset -agU chpwd_functions;
  if [[ -z ${chpwd_functions[(r)_direnv_hook]} ]]; then
    chpwd_functions=( _direnv_hook ${chpwd_functions[@]} )
  fi
fi
```

Source: [dynamic-umask-based-on-cwd.md](https://gist.github.com/laggardkernel/38566f4473068c065f1a1ef15e6e1b4a)